# Combine elements in an Array

Tags: ios, swift

Thank you for reading this question.

> let foodArray = ["pasta", "cheese", "banana", "water"]
>
> let expectedOutput = "pasta;cheese;banana;water"

What would be a good way to convert foodArray to expectedOutput?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let foodArray = ["pasta", "cheese", "banana", "water"]

let expectedOutput = "pasta;cheese;banana;water"
let actualOutput = join(";", foodArray)

let worked = expectedOutput == actualOutput
```

`worked` is `true`.

Comment: Alternatively: `let otherActualOutput = ";".join(foodArray)`

Comment: Thanks Aaron, What if I want to make a function and pass 'strings' in? Thanks a lot.